# How to store a WebElement without having the driver to execute it?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, specflow

I want to store an `Xpath` in a variable without having the `Webdriver` to execute it.

I want to store it in a variable so that I can use it in an if else statement

```
var Resetbtn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='Reset']"));
var Exebtn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[text()='Exe']"));
```

if I remove driver I get the following error `"The name 'FindElement' does not exist in the current context"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindElement` is a method from `IWebDriver`. You can store it in a variable, but without parameters. Instead you can store the `By` as a variable and send it to `FindElement` later

```
By resetBtnBy = By.XPath("//button[text()='Reset']");

var Resetbtn = driver.FindElement(resetBtnBy);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
By reset_xpath = By.XPath("//button[text()='Reset']");
```

and can use it like this :

```
 var Resetbtn = driver.FindElement(reset_xpath);
```